# How do i create a Page Object Model framework in Coded UI VS2013

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I trying to create a Coded Ui framework from scratch for a Web Site that I am testing.

I know that there maybe a better way to approach this, by finding a free version that I could use (e.g. Cuite), but I want to know how it works from the start and have confidence in what it is doing.

Here's what I have set up.

I have a main coded UI directory, an I have created a PageObjects folder that sits at the same level as the Properties and References directories(repositories).

The Page Objects directory contains Sub folders for each PAGE (E.G. Home, Registration, Sign Up, Contact Us.. e.c.t.)

Each Sub folder has a ".uitest" file  (e.g. Home.uitest, Registration.uitest)
In the main folder, there is a UIMap.uitest file that is still present.

```
Page_Objects
------- Home_Page
----------------- NavigateToThe_Home_Page.cs
----------------- RefreshThe_Home_Page.cs
----------------- SelectLinksOnMenuItem_Home_Page.cs
----------------- PAginateThroughInformation_Home_Page.cs
----------------- Home_Page.cs
---------------------------- Home_Page.Designer.cs
---------------------------- Home_Page (partial)
----------------- Home_Page.uitest
------- Registration
----------------- Registration.cs
---------------------------- Registration.Designer.cs
---------------------------- Registration (partial)
----------------- Registration.uitest
UIMap.uitest
```

This seems to be working to a cerain extent, but I an still having issues when run tests from one directory, (Home) in another directory (Registration or even back at the Root level).

I just want to know the best way to use this process as I can't find any clear definition on how to do this.

I'm new to the automation side of things, so please keep thing simple when explaining things to me.

Many thanks

Phil

Answer (score 2):

There's no unique page object model, because there is no need that all the page object model frameworks to be same. so you can create your own framework using page object.

I would recommend you to do what I do,

(1) Create a class test method(perhaps you would already have it). say it is **CodedUI.cs**

(2) You said you already have .uitest files, so make sure you give a **unique name to each uimap.cs**

```
     *HomeUIMap.cs  
     *RegistrationUIMap.cs  
     *ContactUs.cs
```

(3) Now create objects for all the uimap.cs in the codedUI.cs class

```
     *HomeUIMap HomeObj = new HomeUIMap();  
     *RegistrationUIMap RegObj = new RegistrationUIMap(); 
     *ContactUsUIMap ContactUsObj = new ContactUsUIMap();
```

(4) And now you **call the functions** of each page using the object in the order that you want.

Example:
        * HomeObj.NavigateToHome();
        * HomeObj.RefreshHomePage();

Hope you've got an idea now.